# uml relationships in this java code

Tags: java, uml, relationships

I would like to hear what all relationships exists here. I assume that here exists relationships like dependency and aggregation with 1-1 multiplicity?

```
public class Main {

    public Main() {
        Model model = new Model();
        View view = new View();
        Controller controller = new Controller(view, model);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

}

public class Controller {

    private Model model;
    private View view;

    public Controller(Model model, View view) {
       this.model = model;
       this.view = view;
    }

}

public class Model { ... }

public class View { ... }
```

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/q/1687323/2175939

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simple, there is no need here for reverse engineering (constructing the model from code).

`Main` has three associations: one with `Model`, one with `View` and one with `Controller`, while `Controller` has two associations: one with `Model` and one with `View`.

Notice that there is no need for the associations `Main-Model` and `Main-View` because they can be derived via `main.controller.model` and `main.controller.view`.

The association `Main-Controller` (as well as `Main-Model` and `Main-View`) can be viewed/modeled as a *composition*, since a main program instance (a process) is composed of a controller instance, which is bundled with a model and a view instance. All three compositions come with a lifecylce dependency: any model, view and controller instance existentially depends on its main aggregate instance.

Comment: I'd call Main's relationship with Model, Controller, and View a dependency at most, since they are only created in its constructor, and not fields of the class. Odd choice, but still. And you could spend quite some time discussing if controller model and controller view are aggregations or associations. But it'd be time best spent differently so I like how you gloss over that. :)

Comment: You are right, it's not really clear what the intended meaning of this piece of code is. Declaring local variables in the constructor for having references to the model, view and controller doesn't make sense (see, e.g., http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20138948/variables-in-constructor). That's why I interpreted this (without much thought) as intending to have normal references via normal reference properties declared as class members.